# bootstrap dropdown links not styling

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just copied code from the Bootstrap website: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/button-group/#nesting

But my dropdown menu links don't span the menu like these do - am I missing something?

I tried applying this code but to no avail [Bootstrap Dropdown Not Styling Properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690012/bootstrap-dropdown-not-styling-properly)

[image: lin]

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-grey dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      OTHER <span class='caret'></span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `dropdown-menu` needs to be a `ul` list (`<ul class="dropdown-menu"><li>blah</li></ul>`) instead and not anchor tags in a div. That's all you're missing.

Comment: @ChrisW. Not true. Look at Bootstrap's examples

Comment: @j08691 what am I looking for [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#btn-dropdowns) beyond the first line of "Use any button to trigger a dropdown menu by placing it within a .btn-group **and providing the proper menu markup**."?

Comment: PS for the OP, your example is using bootstrap 3.3.7 but you reference v4 in your tag and question. Might want to clarify since there's significant differences between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use these code to solve your problems

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>demo</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Links
   <span class="caret"></span></button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I hope your problems will be solved, Thank You.

Comment: Please explain what you did

Comment: dropdown-menu was hide/show or toggle when clicking on the button through data-toggle="dropdown" and dropdown-menu class is pre-designed.